# How to find a length of a single bone (Drivers)?

Tags: armature, bones, drivers, properties

I'm trying to get a length of a single bone but having no luck to do it when it's last bone in chain. Need that value for custom property (which I need for drivers).

[image]

So far, I've figured out how to find a length of any bone that has parent and child by using **Driver Variable Type: Distance** and select that bone and it's child.

[image]

My question is how to find a length between 'last' bone's head and tail?

I'm sure there must be something easy and obvious way but for last couple of hours had no luck to find solution.

Comment: why don't you just add another bone to your last bone and that you got your length with the same method? ;)

Comment: @Chris I'm actually using that approach at the moment but need to know how to find length of any bone with no tricks ;) I'm sure there's some property we can read to get that info or at least calculate it somehow.

Comment: you can do it via python... ;)

Comment: Is there a way to connect python script with drivers? Haven't done anything like that  before but if there's a way, it's worth of getting into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can connect python script to drivers like this:

[image]

Choose type "scripted expression".

In text editor load "templates" - python - driver functions, so you can see how to make functions accessible in drivers.

Then you can use any function you wrote in the driver.

You can use simple python commands in drivers directly as well (check documentation for that).

So if you create function like this:

```
def bonelength(bone):
    return bone.length
```

and use that in your driver, it should work.

So to try out fast you could use e.g. this code:

```
def bonelength():
    return bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose.bones["Bone.003"].length
```

Of course you have to replace "Armature" with the name of your armature, and "Bone.003" with the name of your bone.

Comment: Actually this worked well. Thanx.

Comment: you are welcome!